# Succinctly split BASH command string into arguments and flags

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, flags

My BASH command string (`$@`) looks like this: `cmd -arg1 foo bar --flag1 --flag2`

Flags come after args, and I don't have any awkward gotchas in the args (I am building an internal tool for my own use).

How can I extract `-arg1 foo -arg2 bar` into `$args` and `--flag1 --flag2` into `$flags`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, although I suspect it is not optimal:

```sh
> echo $x
cmd -arg1 foo bar --flag1 --flag2

> flags="--${x#*--}"

> echo $flags
--flag1 --flag2

> before_flags=${x%%"$flags"}

> echo $before_flags
cmd -arg1 foo bar

> set $before_flags

> echo $1
cmd

> echo $2
-arg1

> echo $3
foo

> echo $4
bar
```

Ref: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 -- How do I do string manipulations in bash?
Ref: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 -- How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?

Comment: It looks like you're treating the argument list as a single space-delimited string, rather than a series of separate arguments (e.g. as an array). This will cause trouble if any arguments contain whitespace and/or filename wildcard characters. Also, it's more normal to have flags *before* regular arguments.

Comment: this doesn't work unless you know with 100% certainty that you'll always have options and flags provided in this same exact format, eg, the proposed code (obviously) does not work for `x="cmd bar --flag2 -arg1 foo --flag1"`; perhaps a nonsensical example but without some idea of the possible combos that you'll have to realistically deal with ...